# How to turn off the monitor via command on Wayland (KDE Plasma)?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, monitor, wayland, xset

I like turning off the monitor when I don't need it, to reduce eyestrain and energy consumption (e. g. when only listening to music). On X11, I have been using the `sleep 0.5; xset dpms force off` shell command and assigned it a custom keyboard shortcut.

Recently, I've switched my entire workflow to Wayland, and the `xset dpms` commands apparently don't work on this platform - output says *`server does not have an extension for dpms option`*.

Is there an alternative method which I can use to turn off the monitor on Wayland?

Comment: I have found an interesting approach: In the Plasma System Settings power configuration (`kcmshell5 powerdevilprofilesconfig`), one can set `When power button pressed` to `Turn off screen`.
I guess this sends some special signal, which might also be callable via qdbus.
I have now downladed the powerdevil kcm source code and try to investigate how it works

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979334/how-to-turn-off-the-screen-in-ubuntu-17-10 has all you need. scripts included.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Kubuntu, so the gnome/mutter-related bus calls won't help

Comment: My current (temporary) solution is: `sleep 0.5 && qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/org_kde_powerdevil invokeShortcut "PowerOff"` .
That works, but only if you have powerdevil configured to turn off the screen when the power button is pressed, so it's not particularly elegant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- `kscreen-doctor --dpms off`
- `sleep 0.5 && qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/org_kde_powerdevil invokeShortcut "Turn Off Screen"`
- `sleep 0.5 && dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kglobalaccel  /component/org_kde_powerdevil org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut string:'Turn Off Screen'`

Also note, there is a native KDE Keyboard Shortcut option that works with Wayland. It is located at `System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Power Management -> Turn Off Screen`.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer doesn't answer the question you asked, frankly.
You accepted a shortcut, but your question is - I think - mostly interpreted as looking for a command line solution.

That shorcut works, and your temporary solution in your comment under your question is almost perfect. Here is the command needed:
`/bin/sleep 1 && /bin/dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kglobalaccel  /component/org_kde_powerdevil org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut string:'Turn Off Screen'`

Basically, the difference compared to your solution:

- don't use qdbus command **as it is deprecated** (good distos ship it with some qt4 tool package still, but only with them, and *they do not install it by default*. Nor should most people install it...)
- you almost got the dbus method call right, but used a wrong shortcut and a hack with power button. It needed 2 minutes more in D-Bus viewer to find `"Turn Off Screen"` argument for `invokeShortcut`

And why would anyone need a command if there is a shortcut?
Because [some people need a command for turning off screen together with screen locking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189677/how-to-turn-off-screen-dpms-together-with-locking-session-in-kde/1336661#1336661)

Anyway, **thank for your answer, as it helped me a lot find the solution to this, and the latter question!!!**

Comment: On my Plasma 5.21.5 your command takes no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, this works for me: `sleep 0.5 && qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/org_kde_powerdevil invokeShortcut "Turn Off Screen"`

Comment: And, by the way, the `qdbus` *command-line tool* is not deprectaed as far as I know.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer!
Funny thing, but with dbus-send you need to add `--print-reply` switch for it to work, but I am too tired to look up why...

Comment: This thread is now a long time ago, but I updated my answer to include possible commands. These days there is also `kscreen-doctor --dpms off`, which is simpler than manual dbus.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at wlr-randr.

Something like "wlr-randr --output <device_name> --off" should work.

Should be in apt (on debian at least).

Cheers

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/emersion/wlr-randr) the code you mean? If I understand the description right, then it only works for wlroots-based compositors, and I don't think `kwin` is.

Comment: Seems like wlr-randr is not the solution. I built it from the above mentioned repository and when running it, I get the following error message: `compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1`. This probably confirms my assumption that it does not work for `kwin`.